# Where to host Chaturbate like websites?

Tags: web-hosting, legal, vps, shared-hosting

I have two questions regarding hosting livecam broadcasting websites:

1. What is your advice for where to host sites like this?
2. What are the hosting requirements?

I need to build a "clone" of chaturbate or cam4 for a client. I know these are not 100% legal websites. Therefore, I need an advice to warn them about hosting issues.

**1. WHERE ?**

What are the most secure and popular hosting providers, which TOS will allow hosting websites on their servers.

**2. HOW ?**

What are the requirements. I have never built a site like this. And as this is broadcasting live cam website - I suppose it has some requirements as RAM, Banwidth or maybe VPS...
Can you tell me which one? Or maybe to give me some hosting package that will be enough for running this.

Comment: We don't allow hosting recommendation questions here.   We have a single catch-all question that may help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what Chaturbate is, but I'm assuming an adult website.

I just did a quick google search and found this company that looks pretty legit: http://www.tmdhosting.com/adult-vps-hosting.html